# how to stop typing in textarea when the page size limit is reached using jquery or jquery-mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am creating textareas dynamically. and i want to type in it till the page limit has reached after that how can i disallow typing inthe textarea? Can anyone help?

```
$("#page1").click( function (event,data) {              
     var newTextAreaDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
    .attr("id", 'TextAreaDiv' + numTextAreaCounter);
     newTextAreaDiv.html('<textarea rows="1" id= "textbox' + 
         numTextAreaCounter+ ' " '+'style="display:block; max-width:50%;
         max-height:50%;height:50px;width:100px; ></textarea>');             

            newTextAreaDiv.className='notes_textarea';
            newTextAreaDiv.appendTo("#page_right");         
            $("#notesfullpage").trigger('create');
            numTextAreaCounter++;   
});
```

Comment: What is a page limit to you?

Answer (score 0):

How about `maxlength` attribute of `textarea`> You can add it and assign the desired value while creating the element.

Answer (score 0):

This way you are explicitly stopping the user to enter characters after the specified characters are typed.

```
$('#textbox' + numTextAreaCounter).keydown(function() {
   var maxLen = $('#textbox' + numTextAreaCounter).val()).length;
e.keyCode = (e.keyCode != 0)?e.keyCode:e.which; 
if(maxLen>50 && (e.keyCode!=8 || e.keyCode!=46))// setting exceptions for backspace and delete key press.
       return false;
});
```

Comment: returning false is not even allowing to delete and type again. Can you help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your user types a character, keypress event is triggered. You can handle this even for all your dynamically generated textareas with `$('#page1').on('keypress', 'textarea', handler)`.

In your keypress handler, you can check the height of a textarea against available space. I don't know the layout of your page so I can't provide a 100% accurate formula to calculate available space, but keep in mind that you have all the dimensions available either through jquery's .height() method or through basic javascript properties such as window.innerHeight. scrollTop property is also available in javascript if you need it.

You can set a flag when you detect that the textarea has reached the page limit and prevent typing when it is on.

The final code would be something like this

```
var outOfSpace = false;

$('#page1').on('keypress', 'textarea', handler);

$('#page1').on('keypress', 'textarea', function() {
    if (outOfSpace)
        return false;
});
```

I haven't tested this. It might be more cross-browser to bind the second handler on keyup or keyup and keypress.

Comment: returning false is not even allowing delete.. how to enable deleting and able to type within the limit?